# is it possible to resize textarea in ipad?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working for a project which needs the textarea that can be resized with user targettouch. But the problem is I can't resize the textarea in ipad as like as in browser.

Can anyone suggest me the reason why?

Comment: It's not implemented by default in the iOS browser. You can implement it with jQuery, though.

Comment: I've seen many plugins but i need one more specification that width of  the textarea should also increase not only height

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of those plugins could be modified to do this. Also, a few probably support that behavior. Google around.